# Angular Directive for displaying the date

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to write an angular directive which will turn `<time datetime="2012-10-11T12:00:00Z"></time>` into `<time datetime="2012-10-11T12:00:00Z">Thu Oct 11 2012</time>`.

My attempt so far looks like this - with myApp already defined: (also on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jphastings/Ns2Ny/3/))

```
angular.module('myApp').directive('time', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    link: function (scope, el, at) {
      el.text((new Date(at.datetime)).toDateString());
    }
  };
});
```

But `at.datetime` isn't populated immediately, so I get `undefined` sent through, and `Invalid Date` is what my view changes to.

I'm sure there's away to specify a one way binding and to re-evaluate on changes, but I'm having a hard time following the documentation! How should I do this?

Comment: Is there a model involved here? Can you share a plunker, fiddle

Comment: I'm not using a model, as I'm only expecting to have the view change with the data (not be a two-way binding). I've tried to put it into a fiddle, but I'm failing miserably. This is where I'm at so far: http://jsfiddle.net/jphastings/Ns2Ny/

Comment: @JP You  need `ng-app="myApp"` in that Fiddle -- your console.log statement never executed because it's not defined in the Angular application that is being used.

Comment: Good spot! Hopefully the new edit will demonstrate my original issue :)

Comment: I don't know what `at.datetime` is, but does `el.text((new Date(scope.temporal)).toDateString()` do what you want?

Comment: (Noted that you've answered your own question below :))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<del>Unless you're using some weird version of Angular, your code shouldn't work at all, because the second argument of `module` is required:</del>

Unless you've already defined `myApp` (which I'm assuming you haven't), your code above, as it is, won't work.  When you're defining a module, the second argument (a list of dependencies) is required:

```
angular.module('myApp', []); // this creates an app (setter)

angular.module('myApp'); // this creates gives you a reference to an already created app (getter)
```

Otherwise your code seems to work fine: http://jsfiddle.net/cjWQB/

That said, depending on what you're doing (or maybe I don't know what a `time` tag is), it might make more sense to create an element directive (instead of an attribute directive) named time.

Update: Based on your Fiddler above, when you define a module, your `ngApp` directive needs to point to that named module.  The only time `<html ng-app>` will work is when you're taking a more simple approach and just using controller functions like:

HTML

```
<html ng-app>
    <div ng-controller="TestCtrl">...</div>
</html>
```

JavaScript

```
function TestCtrl($scope) {
}
```

**Edit**

Based on the changes to your question, since you're using a element directive now, you need to pull the date from a different place.  As Mark suggested in the comments above, that place is `scope.temporal`: http://jsfiddle.net/Ns2Ny/4/

But directly referencing `temporal` in your directive doesn't really make it reusable, so you'll like want to go the extra mile and use `$watch` to indirectly reference the value and keep tabs on it:

http://jsfiddle.net/Ns2Ny/5/

```
angular.module('myApp',[])
.controller('temporalCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.temporal = "2012-11-10T12:00:00Z";
})
.directive('time', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        link: function (scope, el, at) {
            console.log('scope', scope);
            console.log('at', at);
            scope.$watch(at.datetime, function (newValue) {
                el.text((new Date(newValue)).toDateString());
            });

        }
    };
});
```

Make note of my `console.log` statements.  Understanding what's in `scope` and `at` when you're debugging is extremely helpful.

Comment: Thanks for the corrections - I'm not used to getting my code into a fiddle yet! Having got that working, I've realised why my question may seem odd - I've updated my text above.

Comment: I finally figured out what `at` was.  I deleted my comment before I saw your update, but I will add it back so people can follow along.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for :) Thanks! (http://jsfiddle.net/jphastings/Ns2Ny/6/)

Answer (score 3):

Use a filter instead. The built in date filter: [ng-filter:date](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.filter%3adate) will take care of this for you.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/benschwartz/aRBQW/)

```
    <time datetime="temporal">{{temporal|date:'EEE MMM d yyyy'}}</time>
```

(see the angularjs docs link above for all your formatting options)

Comment: A very good point! I'm going to stick with the other answer - but only because I'm going to put some time ago code in there too.

Answer (score 1):

So I figured out what `at` was (I'm used to seeing it as `attrs`).

In your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jphastings/Ns2Ny/3/), since your are specifying scope property `temporal` as a directive attribute value,

```
<time datetime="temporal">it hasn't rendered</time>
```

use [$parse](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24parse) to get that property value inside your directive:

```
.directive('time', function($parse) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        link: function (scope, el, attrs) {
            var model = $parse(attrs.datetime);
            el.text((new Date(model(scope))).toDateString());
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: @Langdon's answer (+1) using $watch is better than $parse if the value of `temporal` may change.